# How does azure functions measure the GBs for billing?

Tags: azure-functions

When running on consumption load in azure functions, how do they actually calculate the billable units?

Is it part of the SDK and events/timings are measured?
Is it the host that profiles the CPU?
Does it profile CPU and Memory every sec and store that? Average it?

I have not found any resources that talk about how it's actually measured.

I ask because it's possible to run code outside the context of "events" and would be nice to know how it's billed/measured.

Answer (score 0):

This page: [Consumption Plan Cost Billing FAQ](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ) has some details on the metrics involved but it doesn't disclose the actual calculation.

> Once you take into account that memory usage can change over time, the
>   calculation is best described as the integral of memory usage over
>   time. **The system does this calculation by sampling the memory usage of
>   the process (and child processes) at regular intervals.** As mentioned
>   on the pricing page, memory usage is rounded up to the nearest 128 MB
>   bucket (so if your process is using 160 MB you are charged for 256
>   MB). This process of calculating memory usage and rounding up takes
>   concurrency (multiple concurrent function executions in the same
>   process) into account.

They recommend using performance counters on the App Service for your own metrics so perhaps that is used for billing as well? Perhaps Paul Batum can share some insights?

> Because Function Execution Units are a combination of execution time
>   and your memory usage, they are not a great metric to use when you're
>   only trying to understand just your memory usage (and potentially
>   optimize your app to use less memory). For this we recommend using the
>   performance counter data collected by App Insights when you enable it
>   for Azure Functions. You can then access this data using the App
>   Insights Analytics portal by running the following query:

```
performanceCounters
    | where name == "Private Bytes"
    | project timestamp, name, value, cloud_RoleInstance
```

Apparently the performance counter is incorrect in some cases as described in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/762).

Comment: Looking for the actual calculation :) So far I have not found any shared information from Microsoft on it. Waiting for someone from the product team to share.

Comment: Yes, I hope @paul-batum can share some light on this.

Comment: I updated the FAQ to clarify that CPU usage is not part of the calculation. Can you help me to understand what additional information you need beyond the explanation already shared that system tracks how long the function runs for and performs a calculation that approximates the integral of the memory usage over time, using regular memory samples?

Comment: I have some functions that using IHostedService / a Task that runs on a static object in the background. I wonder how that is getting billed as its running all the time  and not in a "triggered" function.

Comment: The short answer is don't do that :) You might find your code does not execute reliably if its not done within the context of a function execution. And if does work today, it might not tomorrow as we continue to make the system more efficient.